# How to stitch an above and a below image together after found homography matrix?

Tags: c++, homography, image-stitching

I try to stitch images as

[image]

and

[image]

together after find the homography matrix, But I cann't get that two images in the final result. This is my code.

```
#include < stdio.h>
#include < iostream>

#include < opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include < opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include < opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include < opencv2\gpu\gpu.hpp>
#include < opencv2\stitching\detail\matchers.hpp > 
#include <opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat TwoInOneOut(Mat Left, Mat Right);
void findHomo(Mat cameraFrame1, Mat cameraFrame2, Mat &H, Mat &result);

int main(){
    Mat img3 =imread("33.jpg");
    Mat imgFRL =imread("resultFRL.jpg");

    Mat H3;
    Mat result3;


    findHomo(imgFRL,img3,H3,result3);
    cout << "homography matrix3: " << H3 << endl;
    imshow("result3", result3 );
    //imwrite("result3.jpg", result3 );
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
void findHomo(Mat cameraFrame1, Mat cameraFrame2, Mat &H, Mat &result)
{
    int mode=2;


    if(mode == 0)
    {
        imshow("Left", cameraFrame1);
        imshow("Right", cameraFrame2);
    }

    Mat Left(cameraFrame1.rows, cameraFrame1.cols, CV_8U);
    Mat Right(cameraFrame1.rows, cameraFrame1.cols, CV_8U);
    cvtColor(cameraFrame1, Left, CV_RGB2GRAY, CV_8U);
    cvtColor(cameraFrame2, Right, CV_RGB2GRAY, CV_8U);

    if (mode == 2)
    {
        printf("Homography Matrix Processing\n");
        H = TwoInOneOut(Left, Right);
        mode=1;
        destroyWindow("Left");
        destroyWindow("Right");
    }

    if(waitKey(30) == 'r')
    {
        printf("normal mode\n");
        destroyWindow("Processing");
        mode=0;
    }

    if(H.cols == 3 && H.rows == 3)
    {
        Mat Warping( (Left.rows+Right.rows), max(Left.cols,Right.cols)/*Left.cols*3*/, cameraFrame1.depth() );
        result = Warping;
        warpPerspective(cameraFrame2, result, H, Size(result.cols, result.rows));
        imshow("R1",result);
        /*imwrite("R1.jpg",result);*/

        Mat tempWarpImg1(result,Rect(0,0,Left.cols,Left.rows));
        cameraFrame1.copyTo(tempWarpImg1);
        //cameraFrame2.copyTo(tempWarpImg2);

 //  if(mode ==1)
    //  imshow("Processing", result 

  }

    //if (waitKey(27) == 'q') destroyAllWindows;

}


Mat TwoInOneOut(Mat Left, Mat Right)
{
 Mat H;


 if(Left.channels() != 1 || Right.channels() != 1)
 {
  printf("Channel Error\n");
  return H;
 }

 //Detect the keypoints using SURF Detector
    int minHessian = 100; //1500; 
    SurfFeatureDetector detector( minHessian );
    SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;

 /////////////////
 //A
    std::vector< KeyPoint> kp_Left;
    detector.detect( Left, kp_Left );    
    Mat des_Left;
    extractor.compute( Left, kp_Left, des_Left );

 /////////////////
 //B 
    std::vector< KeyPoint> kp_Right;
    detector.detect( Right, kp_Right );
    Mat des_Right;
    extractor.compute( Right, kp_Right, des_Right );

 /////////////////
 //Match
    std::vector< vector< DMatch > > matches;
    FlannBasedMatcher matcher;
    matcher.knnMatch(des_Left, des_Right, matches, 2);
 //matcher.knnMatch(des_Right, des_Left, matches, 2);
    std::vector< DMatch > good_matches;
    good_matches.reserve(matches.size());  

 for (size_t i = 0; i < matches.size(); ++i)
 { 
  if (matches[i].size() < 2)
   continue;

  const DMatch &m1 = matches[i][0];
  const DMatch &m2 = matches[i][1];

  if(m1.distance <= 0.7 * m2.distance)        
   good_matches.push_back(m1);     
 }

 //Draw only "good" matches
    Mat img_matches;
    drawMatches( Left, kp_Left, Right, kp_Right, good_matches, 
    img_matches, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1), 
    vector< char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS );
    imshow("Match", img_matches);

    /////////////////
 //Find H
    if(good_matches.size() > 20 )
    {
        vector< Point2f >  LeftMatchPT;
        vector< Point2f >  RightMatchPT;

        for( unsigned int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++ )
        {
            LeftMatchPT.push_back( kp_Left[ good_matches[i].queryIdx ].pt );
            RightMatchPT.push_back( kp_Right[ good_matches[i].trainIdx ].pt );
        }

        H = findHomography( RightMatchPT, LeftMatchPT, CV_RANSAC );

    }

 return H;
}
```